# Python - Delete only the third last character from a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to delete only the third last character from a file. I'm trying this:

```
f = open("myfile.json", "r+")
f.seek(-4, 2)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

...But it deletes all the next characters up till the end of file. I want it to delete only 1 character after seeking, instead of deleting all the next characters till the end. Any help will be appreciated.

**My solution (Thanks to NPE's comment):**

```
# After opening file

f.seek(-3, 2)
end_str = f.read()
f.seek(-4, 2)
f.truncate()
f.write(end_str)

f.close()
```

Comment: After you've truncated the file, you'll need to reinstate the last two characters by writing them back. For that, you'll need to have read them before the truncation.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work! Although by adding some very ugly lines.

Comment: @Asym What's your solution? There's possibly a better one.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ See the edit

Comment: @Asym I would've gone with that too! But I believe you can edit files inplace with `fileinput` as well.

Comment: That looks like a good solution too but I'll go with this one for now! Thanks :)

Comment: do you want to delete character from a file, or in stream ?  You can not delete char from a file, data types are used as permanent savings ( like you are saving a game ), if you want to change a data you will need to load it , change it and then overwrite it. 
 
If you want to strip some known characters , i would suggest builtin regular expression module (re).